# Import file from one directory up

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, directory, python-import

I am working to import a file from one directory up.

```
Fitv/
  __init__.py
  BrowserPool.py
  FitvTests/
    __init__.py
    environment.py
```

So with the above file structure, I want to import BrowserPool into environment.

I started with:

```
from Fitv.BrowserPool import BrowserPool
```

And got this:

```
  File "..\environment.py", line 4, in <module>
    from Fitv.BrowserPool import BrowserPool
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Fitv'
```

Looking at various sources I tried:

```
from .. import BrowserPool
```

I got this:

```
  File "..\environment.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .. import BrowserPool
KeyError: "'__name__' not in globals"
```

Tried (used absolute path):

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('D:/Dev/Python/Fitv-master-new/Fitv/'))))
from Fitv.BrowserPool import BrowserPool
```

Got:

```
  File "..\environment.py", line 3, in <module>
    from Fitv.BrowserPool import BrowserPool
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Fitv'
```

Tried (used relative path):

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/Fitv-master-new/Fitv/')
from Fitv import BrowserPool
```

Got:

```
  File "..\environment.py", line 8, in <module>
    from Fitv import BrowserPool
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Fitv'
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: I see you've tried `from .. import BrowserPool`, but just for thoroughness, have you tried `from ..BrowserPool import BrowserPool`?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy, that results in `KeyError: "'__name__' not in globals"`

Answer (score 1):

Imports in Python are always relative to the path that the Python interpreter runs from, and from the path to `environment.py` shown in your trackback that includes a `..`:

```
File "..\environment.py", line 8, in <module>
```

it is apparent that you are running `environment.py` from a sub-directory under the `FitvTests`, rather than the same directory where `environment.py` is located, in which case the `..` in your `import` statement would simply refer to the `FitvTests` directory rather than its parent directory, `Fitv`.

You should either run `environment.py` from the `FitvTests` directory, or if you have a good reason to run it from the sub-directory you currently run it from, use `...` instead to refer to the directory 2 levels up:

```
from ...BrowserPool import BrowserPool
```

Comment: I had though this fixed it but I am still getting the issue `KeyError: "'__name__' not in globals"` when moving up one directory to run the code with `from ..BrowserPool import BrowserPool`. Do you know why this error would be occurring?